# How any trajectory can be linear?

Tags: general-relativity

From [this article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-iframes/#RelRefFraClaMec):

> An inertial coordinate system ought to be one in which free particles move in straight lines. But any trajectory may be stipulated to be rectilinear, and a coordinate system can always be constructed in which it is rectilinear. And so, as in the case of the time-scale, we cannot adequately define an inertial system by the motion of one particle

I don't understand. How it's possible to mangle trajectory and coordinate system in that way that movement of a particle looks rectilinear even if it's totally not?

Look at the picture:

[image]

Movement of second particle is clearly non-rectilinear, how `any trajectory may be stipulated` so the movement of second particle could be rectilinear?

Comment: As long as your path does not self intersect or come arbitrarily close to self-intersection you could get a coordinate system so that your path is on a coordinate axis. Have this axis for example be the length of the path and then you can extend the other axes in atleast a small neighbourhood of the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, consider an exponential curve, $e^x$. This is not linear, right?

If I plot it on a graph with the y-axis scaled logarithmically, it can be plotted as a straight line.

In the case of your P2, you can use a linear y-axis, but locally contract and expand the x-axis as necessary to produce a straight line. Would anybody in their right mind do this? Probably not, but that's not the point - you *could* do it.

Comment: +1 Indeed you could do it, and indeed General Relativity **does** do it.

Comment: @JohnRennie  Ok, homework problem: identify the locations and masses of the objects which cause Path 2 to be rectilinear :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - You've missed the point. The coordinate system is _defined_ so as to make the path rectilinear. There are no masses needed. The coordinate system makes no sense whatsoever with multiple bodies interacting, but the OP specifically quotes, "cannot adequately define an inertial system by the motion of one particle". Note the "one particle" restriction.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  I know that -- was trying to make a joke. Sorry

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Mr. Clueless strikes again.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your reference is from a **philosophy** department and not a scientific dep't,  I would take their positions with a grain of pseudosalt. It looks as though someone heard of nonEuclidean geometry and went hogwild on the premise.

It's sort of like they're claiming they can construct a coordinate system which bends with that particle $P_2$ , which is vaguely like describing a particle's motion in the General Relativistic implementation of gravity -- except we tend to view the latter as a force.

So, for all practical and realistic purposes, a particle moves rectilinearly if&onlyif the sum of all transverse forces is zero.